# how to organize a BibTeX entry

Tags: bibliographies

how to write Bibtex code for the following reference:

> NHTSA (2013 a). U.S. Department of Transportation Releases Policy on Automated Vehicle
>   Development. May 30. Retrieved from National Highway Traffic Safety Administration:
>   http://www.nhtsa.gov/About+NHTSA/Press+Releases/U.S.+Department+of+Transportation+Releases+Policy+on+Automated+Vehicle+Development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following setup:

```
@misc{nhtsa:2013a,
author = "NHTSA",
year   = "2013",
title  = "{U.S. Department of Transportation} Releases Policy 
          on Automated Vehicle Development",
month  = "May 30",
howpublished = "\url{https://www.transportation.gov/briefing-room/us-department-transportation-releases-policy-automated-vehicle-development}",
}
```

Observe the use of the `@misc` entry type and of five[5] fields: `author`, `title`, `year`, `month`, and `howpublished`.

To be able to make use of the `\url` macro that's used inside the `howpublished` field, the `url` and/or `hyperref` packages must be loaded.

Here is how the LaTeX output might look like for three bibliography style choices.

`apalike`

[image]

`plainnat`

[image]

`chicago`

### [image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{nhtsa:2013a,
author = "NHTSA",
year   = "2013",
title  = "{U.S. Department of Transportation} Releases Policy on Automated Vehicle Development",
month  = "May 30",
howpublished = "\url{https://www.transportation.gov/briefing-room/us-department-transportation-releases-policy-automated-vehicle-development}",
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\setlength\bibhang{0pt} % just for this example
\bibliographystyle{apalike} % or: plainnat, chicago, etc
\usepackage[spaces,hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=red]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\RaggedRight
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is probably not the neatest solution (more of a quick fix), but it produces what you ask for:

```
@misc{label,
  title={{U}.{S}. {D}epartment of {T}ransportation {R}eleases {P}olicy on {A}utomated {V}ehicle {D}evelopment. {M}ay 30},
  author={NHTSA (2013 a)},
  howpublished={Retrieved from National Highway Traffic Safety Administration: \url{http://www.nhtsa.gov/About+NHTSA/Press+Releases/U.S.+Department+of+Transportation+Releases+Policy+on+Automated+Vehicle+Development}}
}
```

The curly brackets are to preserve the capitals in the title. I added the date to the title to get it where you want it. I don't know how you want to put in the url, you could change this of course.

Hope this helps